# Не работает .UseKestrel() в ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

[image: Не работает .UseKestrel() в ASP.NET Core]

Есть какие соображения по этому поводу?

Comment: лучше сам код а не картинку.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что картинка вместо кода

Comment: Суть вопроса не в ошибке кода а более глобальна думаю в этом случае тип контента не имеет смысловой нагрузки.

Comment: Это да, но как ты понимаешь картинки не индексируются поисковиками, поэтому если другой человек задастся этим вопросом он наверное не сможет найти именно ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я добавил описание в alt какртинки

Comment: не не не, чувак, проблема вида "не работает" - это совершенно не проблема. Нам абсолютно не ясно, что там у тебя не работает. В вопросе как минимум должен быть **текст** ошибки и минимальный пример, который позволит _воспроизвести_ проблему. У нас есть даже целая статья на эту тему - [mcve]

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, решение найдено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UseKestrel` - это extension-метод. Проверь, есть ли ссылка на [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel).

Comment: Спасибо, данный пакет подключил, теперь ругается на .UseIISIntegration(), не подскажете какой пакет отвечает за него?

Comment: @РоманТимохов *.Server.IISIntegration.dll: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration

Comment: спасибо, ошибки исчезли.